# Get exact day from date string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, date-format

I have checked this SO post: [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Also I have looked into http://home.clara.net/shotover/datetest.htm

My string is: `Mon Jun 24 2013 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

And I want to convert it to `dd-mm-yyyy` format.

I tried using:

```
var dateString = 'Mon Jun 24 2013 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)';
var myDate = new Date(dateString);
var final_date = myDate.getDay()+"-"+(myDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+myDate.getFullYear();
```

But it gives me the result as: `1-6-2013`

The `getDay()` value is the index of day in a week.
For Instance,
If my `dateString` is `Thu Jun 20 2013 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`
it gives output as `4-6-2013`

How can I get the proper value of Day?

P.S: I tried using `.toLocaleString()` and creating new date object from it. But it gives the same result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the day of the month use [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate):

```
var final_date = myDate.getDate()+"-"+(myDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+myDate.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 4):

W3 schools suggests just building your days of the week array and using it:

```
var d=new Date();
var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Sunday";
weekday[1]="Monday";
weekday[2]="Tuesday";
weekday[3]="Wednesday";
weekday[4]="Thursday";
weekday[5]="Friday";
weekday[6]="Saturday";

var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
```

Not super elegant, but usable.

Comment: You noted, that OP wants the date as `dd-mm-yyyy`?

Answer (score 4):

```
var dateString = 'Mon Jun 24 2013 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)';
var myDate = new Date(dateString);
var final_date = myDate.getDate()+"-"+(myDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+myDate.getFullYear();
```

Replace getDay() with getDate().

The above will return the local date for each date part, use the UTC variants if you need the universal time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to take an Array of the days & utilize it using the received index from the `getDay()` method.

Answer (score 0):

To get required format with given date will achieve with moment.js.
a one liner solution is

```
import moment from "moment";

const date = new Date();
const finalDate = moment(date).format("DD-MM-YYYY")
```